# DetailViewController not showing when creates new object

Tags: uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, ios5, nsmanagedobject, pushviewcontroller

Quick question fellas...
The IBAction button is creating a New Object but when the navigator pushes the DetailViewController it's giving me SIGABRT.
Now I'm wondering if I just cannot use the navigation controller function there.
The following code is the one not working correctly

```
- (IBAction)insertNewObject
{
// Create a new instance of the entity managed by the fetched results controller.
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];

Event *newEvent = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];
DetailViewController *detailController = [[[DetailViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

[newEvent setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"timeStamp"];

// Save the context with the new object.
NSError *error = nil;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    //improve this
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}

[detailController setEvent:newEvent];

NSLog(@"Detail Controller New Event 1 (from Master) : %@", newEvent);

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailController animated:YES];
}
```

Now When I select the cell it works perfectly. So the below code works:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"selectSegue"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    Event *event = (Event *)[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"Event on Master:: %@", event);

    DetailViewController *detailvc = [[[DetailViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

    detailvc.event = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"Event on Detail when created :: %@", detailvc.event);

    if (event) [[segue destinationViewController] setEvent:(Event *) [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];  //was: setDetailItem:selectedObject
    [event release];
    [detailvc.event retain];

}
}
```

Feels like I'm missing something simple. But could anyone help me add the object to that DetailViewController without getting a SIGABRT ?
Thanks and Happy New Year everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code seems to be all fine.
For my Experience, you should check if you Set all Mandatory Attributes for the Entity. Because in some Cases the Error statement doesnt mind this error!

Comment: All attributes are marked optional. I think the storyboard is getting me confused. There are so many ways to push a view controller now. But thanks for your help so far.